# concatenate files into 2 data frames using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder with 4 files, I want to concatenate the 2 first files into df1 and the 2 second files into df2

I found this method but actually it concatenates all of the files into one dataframe

```
fiels = #the path
df= pd.concat([pd.read_excel(fiel) for fiel in glob.glob(fiels+ "/*.xlsx")],ignore_index=True)
```

Any suggestions to do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC select files by indexing - first 2 and all another like:

```
files = glob.glob(fiels+ "/*.xlsx")

df1 = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(fiel) for fiel in files[:2]],ignore_index=True)
df2 = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(fiel) for fiel in files[2:]],ignore_index=True)
```